# What do you call a company logo used for ad purpose?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a word for it, but I am asking the question, because I have trouble making a sentence sound fine without such a word. I am not sure if it's one of those cases where we can do nothing about it, but I feel there might be a rarely used word that might be of help.

Here's an example:

> He tattooed a bunch of company logos on his arms for advertisement
>   purpose.

Company logos sounds weird, there must be at least a word that corresponds to company logos even if there's no perfect match for "company logo used for ad purpose".

Comment: Could it be "brand logos" instead?

Comment: Maybe, but I am now wondering if we use the metonym "company brands" instead of saying logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He tattooed a bunch of company *trademarks* on his arms for advertis*ing* purpose*s*."

["A trademark, trade mark, or trade-mark is a recognizable sign, design, or expression which identifies products or services of a particular source from those of others"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark#Oldest_registered_trademarks)

Comment: The word “bunch of” suggests informal spoken English while the word “trademarks” suggests more formal written English.     If “bunch of” is part of the sentence, then the original question “company logos” is **totally fine**.

Answer (score 0):

In sports, companies who financially support a team or an athlete in exchange for advertising are called *sponsors*

> He tattooed a bunch of **sponsor logos** on his arms as advertising.

"Logo" is the word for the image associated with a company or organization.   Sometimes "brand" or "branding" may be used, although this generally refers to the overall marketing strategy, which often includes particular images. For example:

> [The Tattoo As A Corporate Branding Tool - Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/the-tattoo-as-a-corporate-branding-tool-2013-6)